# Automatically add author's name to post_tag

Tags: functions, tags

I need to add the author of a post's name to the post's tags whenever the post is published. So for example John Smith wrote a post, the tag 'John Smith' would be added to that post's tags.

I've tried a couple of different ways, but I think I'm closest with this:

```
 In functions.php:

 add_action( 'save_post', 'add_authors_name');
 function add_authors_name( $post_id ) {
 $post_author = get_the_author($post_id);
 wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, "$post_author", 'post_tag', true );
 }
```

This doesn't work, but I think I'm getting there. Just not sure what I'm missing... Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: You can check what [`wp_set_post_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms) returns -- `$ret = wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $post_author, 'post_tag', true );`.  If it's `boolean false`, a string, or a `WP_Error` object, you've got an error somewhere in your function call. (Also, you shouldn't need to surround `$post_author` in quotes.)

Comment: Thanks! I surrounded it in quotes as it didn't work when it wasn't. Was just making sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [get_the_author()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author)

(**Note**:This tag must be used within The Loop.)

you code may be like this
In functions.php:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_authors_name');
 function add_authors_name( $post_id ) {
 global $post;
 $post_author = $post->post_author;  // returns the Author ID
 // get the author's WP_User object so we can get the Author Name
 $post_author_obj = get_userdata( $post_author );
 $post_author_name = $post_author_obj->first_name . ' ' . $post_author_obj->last_name;
 wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $post_author_name, 'post_tag', true );
 }
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. So close now. It adds a tag, but post_author is the author's ID. Is there a way to change it to the author's name before setting the post terms? I tried get_userdata() but that just broke everything.

Comment: Okay, thank you Ravs and @Pat J. That worked perfectly.