# Adding An Author Tag To Posts Automatically

Tags: custom-post-types, tags, multi-author

I have been researching how to automatically tag a post by author, so if "Peter Parker" authors a post, that post would automatically show up with a tag "Peter Parker." This is because I will have a multi-author blog with custom post types picked up by various blog rolls, and don't want to leave it up to users to remember to tag themselves in every single post.

I came across [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100340/automatically-add-authors-name-to-post-tag) that seemed to be asking the same thing as I'm doing now and ended up with the following code:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_authors_name');
function add_authors_name( $post_id ) {
 global $post;
 $post_author = $post->post_author;  // returns the Author ID
 // get the author's WP_User object so we can get the Author Name
 $post_author_obj = get_userdata( $post_author );
 $post_author_name = $post_author_obj->first_name . ' ' . $post_author_obj->last_name;
 wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $post_author_name, 'post_tag', true );
 }
```

I put this in functions.php and it broke my site.  I had to login to the hosting company and reset the file through ftp.

I then came across [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45398/automatically-assign-posts-by-author-to-a-specific-category) that also provided an acceptable (albeit more messy) approach that would automatically assign authors to specific categories.  That lead me to a plugin that someone replied with but that was from 3 years ago and the plugin no longer worked when I tried to install/activate it.

I then searched more on google but only found a [freelancer.com link](https://www.freelancer.com/jobs/PHP-Wordpress/Auto-tag-author-Wordpress-plugin/?t=b&utm_expid=294858-308.2oso58FbRsuhR3xCT4EBFA.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F) that was *requesting* this kind of plugin be made.

I would appreciate your help.  I've tried to do a good amount of research into this but ended up breaking my site or hit dead ends.  Thank you.

edit: As I was able to explain thanks to  cybmeta's helpful prompts, I do indeed want to eventually try my hand at customizing author.php, but right now I do not have enough know how to even formulate questions acceptable for stackexchange.  This auto-tagging of authors is the last piece of the puzzle for me getting on with my site without coding anything else, so I would be grateful for assistance with that.  Thank you so much for your help so far,  cybmeta.

Comment: A post's author is already assigned to the post (I see you know that as you are using `$post->post_author`). I don't get the point of creating a tag with the author name. What is the purpose of doing it?

Comment: I want to make customized author profiles with through the 'pages' part of wordpress.  Each author would have an individual 'blog roll' content element, but right now this element only picks up categories and/or tags (i.e. there is no option to pick up 'all posts by x author').  So, I want to make the author's name a tag itself so I can easily pick up everything that author posts in their blog roll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your comment, what you want is to create an author archive using tags and customize the author archive pages. You don't need tags or categories for that. There is a built-in author archive, by default the URL is in the format `yoursite.com/author/username`. That URL will show all posts by author and will use the template hierarchy as you can see [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). To customize the author archive you can use the template `author.php`; if you want to customize the archive for a specific author you can use the template `author-{username}.php` or `author-{usernid}.php`.

Also, you can pick up all posts by author using [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts), etc, for custom queries and loops.

Although I don't get the point of tagging posts with author name, here a working and tested code:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_authors_name', 10, 2);
function add_authors_name( $post_id, $post ) {

    // Check the post type to apply only to satandard posts.
    // Bypass if the $post is a revision, auto-draft or deleted
    if( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {

        $post_author = $post->post_author;  // returns the Author ID
        // get the author's WP_User object so we can get the Author Name
        $post_author_obj = get_userdata( $post_author );
        $post_author_name = $post_author_obj->first_name . ' ' . $post_author_obj->last_name;

        if( ! has_term( $post_author_name, 'post_tag', $post ) ) {

            wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $post_author_name, 'post_tag', true );

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  I apprecite your time to go over my inquiry and reply. If I can speak honestly, I don't think this route is viable for me because there are a few more customization I am looking to do to the author archive pages including adding social media icons and separate bio box.  Also, the default author template displays quite poorly on mobile at the moment.

Comment: My solution to all of this was to create custom pages and redirect all calls for individual author pages to these newly built pages.  To implement all of the changes I want, I would have to dive further into customizing the php which I have no idea how to do (and which I've already broken my site with multiple times).  I am learning php on an ongoing basis, and maybe redirecting ot pages is not viable in the long term, but pages are something I am much more familiar with and can implement now.

Comment: I have spent a long time going down both routes (customizing the php which I have no in depth knowledge of vs. redirecting to pages) and I have come to the point where this is the only single piece of coding I would have to do to get the redirection to pages route working (i.e. having the blog roll pick up individual posts by author).  

I _really_ have tried to put the work in to find the solution myself and I feel bad for even asking this above inquiry.  I am just more familiar and confident with using the visual layout editor at this point in my coding education.

Comment: So basically I feel like I'm imposing by even making my original inquiry without a deeper understanding of php and that I should just know how to do it myself.  And to make the kind of author profile I want, I would have to do a few more customizations and make more inquiries (which I don't even feel I'm justified in doing because I don't have the php knowledge to even make an attempt at these other customizations).

Comment: Redirecting to pages for each author is a bit of a messy solution and a bit cluttered compared to editing author.php, but it's something I understand and can deal with at this point.  Sorry for this long explanation.  I just hope to achieve the solution to my original inquiry so I can not bother anyone with more questions.

Comment: Adding social icons, bio, etc, all of that can be done using the template files I was talking about. You can customize that template files as you want. I really don't understand where do you have the problem.

Comment: By the way, you don't bother anyone with questions. That is the prupose of this site ;)

Comment: Thank you for your comments, cybmeta.  I was specifically told not to ask questions without trying out code myself before which lead me to my current path.  The thing is, I don't know how to code AT ALL in the first place, so it would literally require me to start from the very beginning to even formulate an acceptable inquiry for these forums.  I do want to learn php and am trying but it would take several weeks to speak the same language as the experts here, whereas this one little piece of code (auto-tagging authors) is the **only** piece I need to start on the redirection-page path.

Comment: So I would ideally want to know how to auto-tag authors first, make custom pages for them and alongside that learn php, and when I speak enough code to formulate questions here I will start to try to customize author.php (hopefully without breaking my site).  I'd want to try my hand at customizing this file alongside of my 'temporary solution' because it is for something that needs fixing imminently.

Comment: I understand you. If you are going to build pages for authors, that means that you know HTML at least. In that case, I would keep with what I said in the answer: forget redirections; use `author-{id}.php` (replace {id} with user ID of the author) or `author-{username}.php` (replace {username} with username of the author); in php files you can write only HTML as well and you will have a specific page for each author without any redirection.

Comment: I actually don't know HTML either.  Yeah... I know.. I probably shouldn't be running a website lol.  I'm currently using the [Enfold theme](http://themeforest.net/item/enfold-responsive-multipurpose-theme/4519990) which is very much WYSIWYG and I have been building pages entirely with feature called The Avia Layout Builder.  It has allowed me to achieve what I wanted with my website without having to dip into code so much thus far.

Comment: I think you are facing a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); anyway, I've updated my answer with a working code for autho tag posts based on author name.

Comment: thank you so much for this.  i also learned what an XY problem is as well now, so thank you for teaching me about that.  it sounds very much like what happened here and i will try to avoid it in the future.  you are an amazingly helpful person.  i really appreciate you taking the time and being patient!